# How to rewrite the MongoDate class so that I can reuse with new mongodb php driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, mongodate

We are working on a project which currently uses mongodb and yii framework.We are planning to upgrade our project to php7.But the old monogdb driver depreciated.The MongoDate class is part of the old mongo driver and it is depreciated.How to make it work by rewriting this class in our project?

Comment: Are you using Yii or Yii2 ?

Comment: I am using Yii and the Yiimongodbsuite extension.I am currently rewriting the extension to make it work with the new mongo db driver.I am trying to write a custom class for MongoDate since it is depreciated.

Comment: Yii support ended on 31st December 2015 - more then a year ago, which means, it's not getting any updates! Pretty much everything will be outdated for that. I suggest you switch over to Yii2 which has active support and working extensions instead of trying to rewrite database drivers.

Comment: Yeah thats true.But instead of rewriting the whole application,we thought about rewriting the extension currently.

Comment: Mainly I want to know how mongo db converts timestamp to ISO date format.Can you tell me how it is happening so that I can write my own MongoDate class?